# How to broadcast a certain message

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcast

I have created a broadcaster with one `Activity` in which when I click the button the intent in broadcasted.

The problem is that I would like to broadcast a message which is typed in `EditText` contained in the GUI not  just empty `Intent`

```
public void broadcastIntent(View view) {
    sendBroadcast(new Intent("com.example.MESSAGE_INTENT"));//how to insert a string message in it
}
```

Activity's Layout:

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.broadcaster.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/textField"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
        android:onClick="clearTextField"
        android:ems="10" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textField"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textField"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textField"
        android:onClick="broadcastIntent"
        android:text="Broadcast message!" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `Intent.putExtra()` methods to add data to the intent, and the receivers can use the corresponding `Intent.getXxx()` methods to get the data. [See the JavaDoc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html).

Comment: Should I create BroadcastReceiver in the same project?

Comment: If the receiver is part of the same app, then yes (I assume you are talking about an eclipse project).